# Figure height in multirow

Tags: graphics, multirow

Was wondering if there is a way for forcing a figure height placed inside a multirow table, i.e. give the figure a height equal to the number of lines of the multirow cell. MWE follows, where ideally `height=2cm` should be modified to match a height of 3 text lines.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lll}
    \multirow{3}{*}{\includegraphics[height=2cm,keepaspectratio]{PIC}} & blabla & blabla\\
    blabla & blabla & blabla\\
    blabla & blabla & blabla\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `height=3\normalbaselineskip`...

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea why, but Werner's commented answer didn't work for me. Implementing the same idea this way worked, however:

Edit: Werner's answer works, I just read it wrong because I'm sleepy. I'll leave this as an alternate:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\newlength{\length}
\setlength{\length}{3\baselineskip}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lll}
    \multirow{3}{*}{\includegraphics[height=\length,keepaspectratio]{PIC}} & blabla & blabla\\
    blabla & blabla & blabla\\
    blabla & blabla & blabla\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

> [image]